# x86 assembly how to keep updated variables in recursion?

Tags: recursion, assembly, x86, stack

Pseudo code is as follows:

```
function(param1, param2, param3)

mov eax, param1
mov ebx, param2
mov ecx, param3

//a bunch of stuff is done here
//I need to call recursevely so I can do

dec ebx //ebx--
inc ecx //ecx++

push ecx
push ebx
push eax

call function //Needs to call itself with decremented/incremented values

mov edi, eax

pop eax
pop ebx
pop ecx
```

My issue is that when I call the function recursively the `mov` instructions needed for initialization at the very begining will overwrite the modified values if I copy them from stack before the `mov` block. Conversely if I do it after the `mov` block then my initialization phase will get garbage data into those registers since stack wont have any data (it will actually probably just crash because there is no stack at very beginning)....

Its kind of a chicken and an egg situation for me.... any tips?

Answer (score 5):

The solution is trivial, but it may be hard to see the first times: just use the stack to save the caller's registers.

```
function(param1, param2, param3)

push eax
push ebx
push ecx

; Your function body here

pop ecx
pop ebx
pop eax

ret
```

The stack is a natural structure when it comes to recursion.

A trivial implementation of the function will save/restore (a.k.a. spill/fill) all the registers used, but in general there is a contract between the caller and the callee named [the calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention).
This convention mandates which registers (called non-volatile) a caller expect not to be altered by the callee - the exact set is a matter of optimisation and convenience as it moves the responsibility for saving a specific register to or from the caller.

Note that you always have a stack, even before and after an instance of your function is called.
For 32-bit program the standard prologue and epilogue are

```
push ebp                      ;Save caller's frame pointer
mov ebp, esp                  ;Make OUR frame pointer

sub esp, ...                  ;Allocate space for local vars

;Save non-volatile registers

push ...
push ...
push ...

;Function body
;
;[ebp+0ch] = Parameter 2 (or N - 1)
;[ebp+08h] = Parameter 1 (or N)
;[ebp+04h] = Return address
;[ebp] = Caller frame pointer
;[ebp-04h] = First local var
;[ebp-08h] = Second local var
;...

;Restore block
pop ...
pop ...
pop ...

;Restore ESP (Free local vars)
mov esp, ebp
pop ebp          ;Restore caller's frame pointer
ret              ;If a callee cleanup calling convention put the number of bytes here
```

This code keeps the arguments and the local vars at fixed addresses relative to the frame pointer (pointed by `ebp`) independently of the size of the local variables.

If your function is simple enough or if you are confident with the math, you can omit the creation of the frame pointer.
In that case accessing the arguments or the local variables is done with different offsets in different parts of the function body - depending on the stack of the stack at the moment.

### Example

Let's assume the calling convention mandates that `ebx` and `ecx` are non-volatile, that `eax` is the register holding the return value, that the parameters are pushed right to left and that the callee cleans up the stack.

If we omit the frame pointer the function can be written as

```
function(param1, param2, param3)

;EBX and ECX are non-volatile, so we save them on the stack since we
;now we are going to use them
push ebx
push ecx

;Move the arguments into the registers
;You need to adjust the offset to reach to the parameters
mov eax, param1                ;eg: mov eax, [esp + 0ch]
mov ebx, param2                ;eg: mov ebx, [esp + 10h]
mov ecx, param3                ;eg: mov ecx, [esp + 14h]


;The logic of the function
dec ebx
inc ecx

;---Recursive call---

;The function won't save eax, so we save it instead
push eax         

;Do the call    
push ecx
push ebx
push eax
call function

;Here eax is the return value, but ebx and ecx are the same as before the call

;Save the return value in EDI
mov edi, eax

;Restore eax (Now every register is as before but for EDI)
pop eax                  

;Other logic ...

;Epilogue

;Restore non volatile registers
pop ecx
pop ebx

ret 0ch
```

Note how `edi` is volatile and thus we don't need to save it for the caller, if you happen to do the recursive call with something in `edi` then you need to save/restore it exactly like `eax`.
If the calling convention mandated `edx` to be non-volatile we could have saved `eax` by moving it into `edx` before the call.
This as the expense of having a `push / pop edx` in the prologue/epilogue - showing how the calling convention shifts the line between the caller and the callee responsibility.

Comment: Hi Margaret, thanks for the very detailed reply. I understand the calling convention and saving registers etc. I dont have any issues writing non recursive assembly (when a function calls another function and passes parameters etc). However when function calls itself my main issue is passing it updated parameters without overwriting them with the block of code that moves the initial parameters into registers. From my understanding those initial parameters that were passed stay static. I can think of one way, doing an if statement equivalent to see if its the initial run? But that seems hacky?

Comment: would updating the parameters through `mov param1, eax` and then calling the function be valid? That way the initialization block will pick up the new values?

Comment: @Duxa, Sorry for my late reply. I'm glad to see you already figured it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after a lot of reading up I found out that I had a fundamental misunderstanding, once it clicked I got it. So for anyone that finds this in the future.

When function is called (in C/C++) the parameters are put on the stack, so instead of reading off the parameters like `mov eax, param1`, what you should do actually read it off the stack to begin with `mov eax, [esp+8]`.

This way when you call the function recursively you can always read off the stack, including your very first execution of the function.

My misunderstanding was that I thought parameters are passed to the function some other way when called through C and stack way was only for assembly. But no, as Margaret above said it all follows convention.

So this also made me really appreciate the convention and really understand the importance of it. It makes things A LOT EASIER!

Thanks very much for your help guys!

Comment: Keep in mind that many calling conventions _don't_ pass (most of) the parameters on the stack, such as the x86-64 calling convention which prefers registers. This doesn't prevent recursion, however - it just means the recursive function should store its parameters, passed in registers, on the stack before making a recursive call. The code looks almost the same, but it is the current parameter values being pushed on the stack rather than the parameters for the next recursive call.